# Styles don't apply to sub-child routes in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-routing

I was trying to add two sub-child routes to a child route as seen below, but when I execute the code the styles don't apply to the sub-child components and the console shows the following error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/stations/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
```

And here's how I added the sub-child routes:

```
{
    path: '', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'stations', component: StationsComponent, 
        children: [
        {path: 'add', component: AddComponent},
        {path: 'edit', component: EditComponent}
      ]},
      { path: 'vehicles', component: VehiclesComponent}
    ]
  }
```

and therefore not accepted as a valid stylesheet

[image]

I'm looking forward to your help.

Comment: Please provide more details like where are you applying styles from? Is it a component level style or global style file(style.css)? And what do you mean by "execute the code"? Do you mean "ng serve" ? or you built your app  (ng build) and then trying to run it?
In the later case, most likely it looks like a server misconfiguration

Comment: I'm applying styles from the component level, the error has occurred when I run the server by ng serve.

Comment: have you tried restarting the `ng serve` ? The css file is corrupted, so either you have a BOM in it, or it is misbuilt, or you got a weird angular.json config...

Comment: Yeah, I did it but no changes. the style of the parent component doesn't apply to the sub-child component, there's only HTML there.

Comment: what we see is `http://localhost:4200/stations/styles.css`, it should be `http://localhost:4200/styles.css`. Is there any basehref config (in the index.html) ? Lazy-loading ? strange routing stuff ?

Comment: Definitely, there is a baseref in the head of index.html as following:
`<base href = "/">`

Comment: I remember sometimes it happens when the HTML messes up. Inspect the HTML in the console, and I guess you should find that your app.component is included twice (so inside you `<app-root>`, you see again the root `<header>` including all js includes... If you see that, check every request, and you may find one of your request contains the index.html instead of the actual expected content.

Comment: I mean I guess what you will see is `<header>...</header><body><app-root><header>...</header><body><app-root>...</app-root></body></app-root></body>`

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant guess @Random, the problem solved. I missed including the head closing tag in the ```index.html``` file. You really deserve a big thumb up.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was missing `</head>` closing tag, in the file `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Check the index.html file. In my file i missed the . I added it and the project worked.